# Android AccountManager.getUserData() works without same sharedUserID as opposed to documentations

Tags: android, accountmanager, userid

i have two applications that share the same authenticator code.

Both apps are signed with the same signature.

UID in the manifest file is not set for any of the apps.

I cannot uninstall and reinstall the apps or change their UID in the manifest file as they are both already published to google play.

AccountManager.getUserData() and AccountManager.setUserData() documentation state that in order to call them the caller UID should be the same as the authenticator UID in addition to the same signature.

If i try to call AccountManager.getUserData() from any of the apps i don’t get any exception even though they don’t share the same UID(it contradicts the documentation).

Am I missing something here?
Thanks.